# default sort and sortableattributes for CListView

Tags: php, yii

In my ClistView i'm trying to set a default sort and define my sortable attributes in my view. I've gotten this far

in my `actionIndex()`

```
$criteria=new CDbCriteria(array(                    
                            'condition'=>'make_code!="00"', 
                    ));

$dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('StoreNew', array(
                    'criteria'=>$criteria,
                    'sort'=>array(
                       'defaultOrder'=>'_make DESC',
                        'attributes'=>array(
                            '_make'=>array(
                                'asc'=>'_make',
                                'desc'=>'_make DESC',
                            ),
                          '*', //if attributes contains a star ('*') element, the name will also be used to match against all model attributes.
                        )
                    ),
        ));
```

in my model

```
public function relations()
    {
        return array(
            '_state' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'State', 'state'),
            '_make' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'pMake', '', 
                            'foreignKey' => array('make_code'=>'make_code')),
        );
    }
```

and in my view

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'itemView'=>'_view',
    'sortableAttributes'=>array(
        '_make' => 'Make',
        'store',
        'state',
    ),
));
```

im getting this error

```
CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '_make' in 'order clause'. The SQL statement executed was: SELECT * FROM `store_new` `t` WHERE make_code!="00" ORDER BY _make DESC LIMIT 10
```

how to i sort table `pMake.make`?

Comment: Are you sure that your `store_new` table contains `_make` column?

Comment: the column name is `make`, i used `_make` so i dont get confused when calling it in the view. which i call like this `$data->_make->make` is that wrong?

Comment: btw `$data->_make->make` works just fine in my view

Comment: you can use  _make.make

Comment: @YatinMistry i get this ` CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '_make.make' in 'order clause'. The SQL statement executed was: SELECT * FROM `store_new` `t` WHERE make_code!="00" ORDER BY _make.make DESC LIMIT 10`

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10880372/yii-sortable-attributes

Comment: @YatinMistry tried this. ` //'defaultOrder'=>'make DESC',
      'attributes'=>array(
         'make'=>array(
          'asc'=>'make',
          'desc'=>'make DESC',
         ),
        '*', //if attributes contains a star ('*') element, the name will also be used to match against all model attributes.
       )` when i remove the `defaultOrder` i dont get any errors, but it doesnt sort properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this in your `actionIndex()`

```
$criteria=new CDbCriteria(array(                    
                                'with' => array('_make'),  // join the _make relation you defined in your model into this query
                                'condition'=>'t.make_code!="00"',
                        ));
```

then

```
$dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('StoreNew', array(
                    'criteria'=>$criteria,
                    'sort'=>array(
                       'attributes'=>array(
                            'make'=>array(
                                'asc'=>'_make.make',
                                'desc'=>'_make.make DESC',
                            ),
                          '*', //if attributes contains a star ('*') element, the name will also be used to match against all model attributes.
                        )
                    ),
        ));
```

then in your view

```
'sortableAttributes'=>array(
    'make' => 'Make', //you can call "make" base on 'attributes'=>array('make'=>array())
    'store',
    'state',
),
```

note tested. hope it works.